# Our donation pages are down

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, permissions

There are code snips and what not at the top of our donation pages....and people cannot donate.  Help!

[image]

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem. Do anonymous users have permission to make contributions?

(The Notice errors don't look like they're actually breaking everything.)

Comment: See below.  I never changed any of that anywhere...and now I can't get into the back end of things like I used to be able to.  I haven't touched anything in contributions or anything since mid December.

Comment: Check contribution page is public or not on contribution page title page configuration.

Comment: Also there is some notice on the page related to setting page. To fix this issue  follow the below step. 1 . Logon to your  site.   2. Go to civicrm admin dashboard. 3. Go to administrator console page  and select enable component link. 4. Just enable the contribution pledge option on this page and click on save button.    Done

Comment: This option only exists on event pages, not contribution pages.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew West's comment seems to be correct.  There are two different things happening here - or three, depending on how you look at it.

The most important is "Permission Denied".  I just visited your site, and confirmed you're running Drupal as your website software.  Go to this page:  www.mcuw.org/admin/people/permissions.  In the "CiviCRM" section, find "CiviContribute: make online contributions", and make sure that it's checked off for both "Anonymous User" and "Authenticated User".  Note that you'll need to be a Drupal administrator to view that page; if you're not, please contact your website administrator.

Second - you're getting notices on the top of the page.  Those notices shouldn't affect anything, but they're bad for the donors to see, it erodes trust.  You should hide those.  A good explanation of how to do that is [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35589/how-to-prevent-warnings-from-displaying-to-anonymous-users).

Third - I'm not sure why you'd be getting those notices at all.  You may want to ask your website administrator if there are any customizations they can think of that might lead to those notices appearing.

Comment: I am the website administrator and haven't touched anything in the back end for a week or so at least.  We've had other projects going on.  I have no idea what happened or who changed what...because it wasn't me.  It won't let me go to the page you gave me...says I don't have rights to go to it.

Comment: I don't know how to code drupal, haven't touched anything at all in the back end of our site...short of putting up a document or image (normal stuff) since mid december.

Comment: I used to have all the civicontribute, campaign, etc etc etc areas.  but they are all gone and I can't add another screenshot to this, but I have: search, contacts, administer and support.  If I go into users and permissions under administer, i have "access control", but i can't get into the drupal access control...which I have never been in or changed to begin with.

Comment: @ashleighmchenry - I don't know what you mean by "drupal access control" or "the back end of things".  Can you please include URLs to avoid ambiguity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your hosting company to resolve. United Way has vendors (OneEach Technologies, etc.) that provide website/hosting/civicrm packages to many UW affiliates that manage the backend configuration of your website.

You do not have the permissions to make the changes needed to fix this. Your hosting company does.